# How would I translate this Swift to Obj-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, skmaps

This is probably simple enough, but Im not a regular iOS dev but have a decent understanding of Obj-C and Xcode however not so much with Swift yet.

I am playing around with a mapping SDK called [Skobbler](http://www.skobbler.com/) and downloaded both Swift and iOS examples. 
The Swift example gives me some useful text/console logs of directions turn by turn however the Obj-C doesn't and having a tough time exposing them.

The Swift example looks like this

```
let advices: Array<SKRouteAdvice> =  SKRoutingService.sharedInstance().routeAdviceListWithDistanceFormat(SKDistanceFormat.Metric) as! Array<SKRouteAdvice>
    for advice: SKRouteAdvice in advices
    {
       let instructions = advice.adviceInstruction
       print(instructions)
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSArray<SKRouteAdvice *> *advices = [[SKRoutingService sharedInstance] routeAdviceListWIthDistanceFormat:SKDistanceFormat.Metric];

for (SKRouteAdvice *advice in advices)
{
    NSLog(@"%@", instructions);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
NSArray *advices = [[SKRoutingService sharedInstance]routeAdviceListWithDistanceFormat:SKDistanceFormat.Metric];
for (SKRouteAdvice *advice in advices) {
NSLog(@"%@", [advice adviceInstruction]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

as! doesn't need translating - the compiler will just believe you (you might want to add an assert for identical behaviour). The print is replaced with NSLog (@"%@", instructions).